# How do call Javascript function from a input form in php, to change HTML

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm trying to create a form that, upon submission, will display the first name, mood selected, the latitude and longitude of the user. I'm not having any luck calling the javascript function when I click the input form, I've tried placing the Javascript in/out of PhP, I've also place the code sections in different order. What am I doing wrong?

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>

  <h3>PHP HTML Form radio button Example</h3>   
  <form name="UserInformationForm" method="POST" action="#">
  Enter Your Full Name :
  <input name="FullName" type="text" value="<?php echo $_POST['FullName']; ?>"><br/><br/>
  You are :
  <input name="feelings" type="radio" value=" happy" <?php if($_POST['feelings']=="happy") echo "checked=checked"; ?> > Happy
  <input name="feelings" type="radio" value=" sad" <?php if($_POST['feelings']=="sad") echo "checked=checked"; ?> > Sad 
  <input name="feelings" type="radio" value=" busy" <?php if($_POST['feelings']=="busy") echo "checked=checked"; ?> > Busy
  <input name="feelings" type="radio" value=" excited" <?php if($_POST['feelings']=="excited") echo "checked=checked"; ?>> Excited
  <br/><br/>
  <input type="submit" name="BtnSubmit" onclick="getLocation()"></input>
  </form>

  <?php

  if(isset($_POST['BtnSubmit']))
  {
  echo "<h3>Your form data as bellow</h3>";
  echo "<p>Your Name: {$_POST['FullName']} </p>";
  echo "<p>Your are: {$_POST['feelings']} </p>";
  echo "<p>at: </p>" . "<p id=\"demo\">" . "Here</p>";
  echo '<script type="text/javascript">
        var x=document.getElementById("demo");
        function getLocation(){
        if (navigator.geolocation){
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
        }
        else{x.innerHTML="Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";  }
        }
        function showPosition(position) {
        x.innerHTML="Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
        "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;  
        } </script>';

    }

    ?>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend placing your javascript in the head section of your page instead of inside your php.
Upon form submission i would append my geolocation info to a dom element.

Comment: how would I append the info to a dom element upon submission? Would I add an "onclick" or "onsubmission" attribute to the submit button?